# How can I allow a user to drag content in a layer below the top layer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a need to allow users to drag content that is behind other layers or visible through the transparent part of a layer.

Here's the best way I can describe it: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Tfk2p/1/)

In the example, I want to be able to drag layer 2 around in between layers 1 and 3. I'm not sure this is even possible. It's easy enough to make all of the layers draggable, but I need layers 1 and 3 to stay still while a user positions layer 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create something like a **pipe** by forwarding any event of interest to that element. This can easily be done by invoking jQuerys `.trigger()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)</sup>

```
var $layer2 = $('div#container>#layer-2'),
    $layer3 = $('#layer-3');

$layer3.bind('click mousedown mouseup', function(e) {
    $layer2.trigger(e);
});
$layer2.draggable();
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/Tfk2p/3/

This is just a demonstration. In production code you should store a reference for the target element and only forward events over that reference. (updated that)

Comment: About your last comment, is that because the selector $('div#container>#layer-2') is looking for that element every time one of those events occurs on layer-3?

Comment: @scottm: exactly. Every time `click`, `mousedown` or `mouseup` occurs on `#layer-3`, it requeries `#layer2`.

Comment: If I want to switch this binding around (say there are more layers than this and I only want to forward to the "active" layer) can I store a reference to whatever bind() returns and unbind just that?

Comment: @scottm: you need a way to know which layer is active (e.g. attach a property to the node), and yes you can just call `.unbind(click mousedown mouseup` and `.bind()` another node. You can even create a namespace to bind/unbind, have a read for `.bind()` here: http://api.jquery.com/bind/